# SSRS: Hour() for 24:00

Tags: sql-server, function, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I was using `Hour(Fields!tempo.Value)` for get the hour from a field (tempo). The problem came when I got for first time "24:00" and the report shows the '#error'.

The description in 'Hour' function said:

> Returns an Integer value from 0 through 23 representing the hour of
>   the day

So, I changed the expression to

`=IIf(Fields!tempo.Value = "24:00", 0, Hour(Fields!tempo.Value))`

but yet I get the #error. Then I tried:

`=IIf(Fields!tempo.Value = "24:00", 0, 1)`

and correctly I get "0" for 24:00 values and "1" for the rest.

1. I don't understand why `Hour()` won't work under `IIf()`.
2. Maybe exist some better workaround for this case and I don't know it.

Thanks in advances

EDIT:

The idea is get all events which started between 2 hours every day (for filter events from the morning, afternoon and night):

```
=IIf(Hour(Fields!tempo.Value) >= 22 Or Hour(Fields!tempo.Value) <= 6, SHOWTHIS, Nothing)
```

Comment: Is the "24:00" coming from the database and what data type is that field? And if the data is the result of a stored proc, you should convert it in t-sql prior to the report.

Comment: the field is varchar and it isn't from a stored procedure.

Comment: Embedded query in SSRS? can you show it?

Comment: is 24:00 a time of day?  It is often considered to be incorrect, and said that it should be written as 00:00.

Comment: @WEI_DBA, I'm not sure if I can share the query, but I edited the question with the final expression I'm using and I think is more clear. If yet do you have some question let me know. Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton, the form in the app where people enter the time don't have this kind of validation. Somebody write "00:00", others "24:00".

Comment: @HEDMON - I think I know what's wrong, IIF always evaluates both the arguments you pass to it - Therfore you can't use a condition to prevent a runtime error - does IF work the same way there?

Comment: Hour(IIf(Fields!tempo.Value = "24:00", "00:00", Fields!tempo.Value))     this might avoid HOUR ever acting on '24:00' - it's a problem with IIF, it always evaluates both sides, regardless of the true/false condition, then discards the false one.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton you are right, and thanks to your comment I understand now the solution from alejandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't need to perform operations with the hour you can work with strings to get the hour, also if your dataset returns a string this is the simplest solution (IMO).

Try using this expression:

```
=IIF(LEFT(Fields!tempo.Value,2)="24","0",REPLACE(LEFT(Fields!tempo.Value,2),":",""))
```

If you still want to get the hour using `HOUR` function you have to validate twice your field, in the `IIF` and inside the `HOUR` function:

```
=IIF(Fields!tempo.Value="24:00",
0,
HOUR(IIF(Fields!tempo.Value="24:00","0:00",Fields!tempo.Value))
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Gracias! I will accept the answer @Andrew because solve directly the problem, but I appreciate your time and even if was a littler more longer, it's also a solution. Thank you very much. You have my UV ;)

Comment: @HEDMON, The answer (actually a comment) posted by Andrew 15 minutes ago is the same answer I posted 40 ~ minutes ago. Good luck.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I was looking just the first version of your answer, but you are right. Accepted.

Comment: not exactly the same as what I posted - it has a section that is similar - but I'm glad it all helps!